# How to get the image matrix with matplotlib to get the image matrix without using plt.savefig?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am  doing the process of converting heart sound into graphs to feed convolutional neural networks.I used matplotlib.pyplot.plot to draw a heart sound map, but I don't know how to get the image.Some people save it as .jgp or .png with matplotlib.pyplot.savefig and then get the image matrix through cv2.imread().My question is whether I can get the picture matrix without using matplotlib.pyplt.savefig, but get the picture matrix directly.

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
x = np.linspace(-3,3,50)
y1 = 0.1*x
y2 = x**2
 
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y1,linewidth = 10,zorder = 2,label = r'$y_1\ =\ 0.1*x$')
plt.plot(x,y2,linewidth = 10,zorder = 1,label = r'$y_2\ =\ x^{2}$')
 
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')

plt.show()
plt.savefig("image path")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpONT.png)

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you are taking a one-dimensional data set (i.e. a time series), plotting it, converting the plot to an image, getting the image as a 2-d array, and feeding that into a CNN?  That's a bit convoluted (pun intended).  All the information is in the original time series. Converting it into an image for processing loses information and wastes CPU cycles. Surely there must be a better way...

Comment: Do you have research?Do you have any other ideas?